# JOOMLA - Instalación error

Tags: joomla3

quiero instalar Joomla en mi Hostgator, sin embargo no procede, ya que me sale un error: 
JFolder::create: Could not create folder.Path: /home/packages 
Update package URL

Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puede ser un error de permisos. 
puedes verificar estos pasos:

```
1/ FTP: make sure that you do not enable FTP via Admin > Global 
Configuration > Server > FTP Settings.
2/ Files/folder permission: go to Admin > System > System Information > 
Permission Folders, make sure that all files/folder in this list are 
Writable, except file 'configurastion.php'.
```

PD: no soy experto en joomla, sólo un par de veces lo pude usar, pero creo me había pasado algo similar y era problema en los permisos.

Comment: las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad, toda vez que si la página deja de estar online la información se pierde; por favor añade lo relevante del link aquí

Comment: ya la modifiqué amigo! muchas gracias por el comentario

Comment: Gracias Jose! No logro aun hacerlo pero ojala lo pueda resolver pronto.

Comment: Te deseo lo mejor, lamento no poder ayudar más!